# How to reduce apk Expo size

Tags: react-native, expo, apk

I built an app with expo. now when i do expo build:android , the size in the end is like 50MB!

I saw in the internet that there is a way to reduce it somehow to 10mb.

I try all the tutorials with react-native-init and another ways but dont get it and confused in the middle of the process.

somebody can help me with that please?

Answer (score 0):

You can try building the app to Android App Bundle (.aab), which can reduce the installation size.

`expo build:android -t app-bundle`

ref:
https://docs.expo.io/introduction/walkthrough/#android-and-the-google-play-store
https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle

Comment: The file size of aab maybe similar (or larger) than apk
But the installation size will be less than apk one

Currently there's no way to reduce the expo build bundle since all supported native library are inside the bundle.

Comment: Ive heard about ways to convert the expo to native app and reduce the size to 10mb. . . R u sure?

Comment: So u say that every ezpo app ia more than 40mb? Because my app ia small..

Comment: @RoeiGrinshpan are you talking about this one: https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/master/managed-app-size.md#opt-in-to-manual-lean-builds-on-android
android.enableDangerousExperimentalLeanBuilds can excluded native code for expo-* modules, but will have some risk for OTA update, and iOS is not supported.